# Reading Crc of applications

Tags: c++, linux, stl, mmap, crc

I want to store the crc in the program. To do this, create the file containing the next structure

```
 struct CRC_DATA {
    uchar label[16];
    ulong crc;
} crcData = {{"fdgnrtrbdbd"}, 0};
```

I get size of file

```
struct stat fileStat;
int size = 0;
if(!stat(path.c_str(), &fileStat)) {
    size = fileStat.st_size;
}
return size;
```

To find a place to store the crc do the following

```
int map_ = shm_open(path.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
if (map_ == -1) {
    closeFile();
    return false;
}
ftruncate(map_, size);
void* mapView_ = mmap(0 , size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, map_, 0);
```

mapView_ points the beginning of the file in memory.

```
uchar* base = static_cast<uchar*>(mapView_);
uchar* fileEnd = base + size;
uchar* labelStart = std::search(base, fileEnd, crcData.label, crcData.label + sizeof(crcData.label));
```

Check it

```
if (labelStart == fileEnd) {
    errorStream_.clear();
    errorStream_.str("");
    errorStream_ << "In file '" << fileName_ << "' don't find crc";
    return false;
}
```

When I run application, it get me error "In file fileName don't find crc".
Why i have labelStart == fileEnd?

Comment: Did the shared-memory object exist before you opened it? If so, did it contain the string you're searching for? Do you actually want to open a shared-memory object rather than a normal file?

Comment: Also, what is the value of `size`, and how do you get it?

Comment: Also, you're searching for the string `"fdgnrtrbdbd"` followed by 5 zero-valued bytes, since you're initialising an array of size 16 with only 11 characters and then using `sizeof` to specify the search string's length. That's probably not what you want to do.

Comment: The code which I have given above, I use to build the program. It is located on the value of path. I write how I get size.